# Python: Efficienctly calculate mean of off-diagonal elements for Cadzow filter

Tags: python, performance, filter, data-processing

I have currently implementing a Gadzow filter in Python.

To put in some context. You begin with an 1 dimensional array (let's take range(10) as an example) and build a Hankel-like matrix out of it like

```
H= [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Afterwards you do some linear algebra with this matrix which is no problem. Afterwards, the most time consuming step follows which is an averaging problem.

In a new matrix B you average the elements of the resulting matrix. In the first row you average all elements by the path which is given by the accurances in H. So something like the off diagonals but going from top right to bottom left. In the second slice you ignore the first line and so on.

Matrix $H$ would be invariant under this analysis step but for example the Matrix

```
1 2 2 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

would become

```
1 1.5 1.33 1
1 1   1    1
1 1   1    1
```

Okay, I hope you understand the problem. My (working but inefficient) code is

```
def av_diag(A,i,j):
    dim = A.shape
    # get the "borders" of A
    lim = min((dim[0]-i,j+1))
    # calculate the mean
    return np.mean([A[i+it,j-it] for it in range(lim)])

def avHankel(A):
    # get the mean for all elements by nested list comprehension
    return np.array([[av_diag(A,i,j) for j in range(len(A[0]))] for i in range(len(A))])
```

This takes a while for my data, containing 2048 data points, resulting in a 1024x1023 matrix.

And I would be glad for possible tricks to speed this up.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convolve your input matrix with a *filter* matrix to speed up your code. The *filter* matrix can be defined so that at each step of the convolution, it extracts only the antidiagonals at the given coordinates. Basically, your *filter* matrix is simply an anti-identity matrix. Finally, as the convolution will only sum the elements of the anti-diagonals, you have to divide the output by the correct number of samples to obtain the mean:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
from time import time


def av_diag(A,i,j):
    dim = A.shape
    lim = min((dim[0]-i,j+1))
    return np.mean([A[i+it,j-it] for it in range(lim)])

def avHankel(A):
    return np.array([[av_diag(A,i,j) for j in range(len(A[0]))] for i in range(len(A))])


def fast_avHankel(A):
    m, n = A.shape
    filt = np.eye(m)[:,::-1]
    Apad = np.pad(A, ((0, m-1), (m-1, 0)), mode = "constant", constant_values = 0)
    Asum = fftconvolve(Apad, filt, mode = "valid")
    Adiv = np.array([ [ min(m-i, j+1) for j in range(n) ] for i in range(m) ])
    return Asum / Adiv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = np.random.rand(500, 500)

    starttime = time()
    Hold = avHankel(A)
    print(time() - starttime)    # 10.6 seconds on a laptop

    starttime = time()
    Hnew = fast_avHankel(A)
    print(time() - starttime)    # 0.26 seconds on a laptop
```

Comment: this looks great, I have to think about, what you are doing, but thanks a lot